# Volume growth of black hole interior

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, event-horizon, black-hole-firewall

I have been reading about Susskind's $Complexity = Volume$ conjecture from a set of lecture notes. In these, he gives an equation for the growth of the interior of an AdS-Schwarzschild black hole:

$$ \frac{dV(t)}{dt} \sim l_{ads}AT$$

where V is the volume of the BH interior, $l_{AdS}$ is the AdS length scale, A is the horizon area and T is the BH temperature. He does not derive this equation but says that it can be easily calculated from the AdS metric or deduced by dimensional analysis. I tried the former method but I'm not sure how to integrate the metric such that only the interior volume is considered. Could someone perhaps give me a hint as to how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that Susskind arrived at the growth rate heuristically by considering the horizon as a codimension two hypersurface and then integrating over the radius of AdS space. Let's assume that the *volume* growth rate is constant with respect to Euclidean time to make the following argument. The SAdS$_4$ metric, and its volume form are given by
$$\text{d}s^2 =g^E_{\mu\nu}\text{d} x^\mu\text{d} x^\nu= f(r)\text{d}t_{E}^2 + f(r)^{-1}\text{dr}^2 + r^2 \text{d}\theta^2+r^2\sin(\theta)^2\text{d}\phi^2,\\
\sqrt{\det{g}^E}\varepsilon = r^2\sin(\theta)\text{d}t_E\wedge\text{d}r\wedge\text{d}\theta\wedge\text{d}\phi.$$ Now consider the codimension two surface normal to the $t_E-r$ disk evaluated on the horizon given by
$$\text{d}s_\partial^2 =h_{ab}\text{d}x^a\text{d}x^b= r_h^2\text{d}\theta^2 + r_h^2\sin(\theta)^2\text{d}\phi^2,\\
\sqrt{\det{h}}\varepsilon_\partial = r_h^2\sin(\theta)\text{d}\theta\wedge\text{d}\phi.$$
If we integrate the codimension two volume form, we get the surface area of the SAdS$_4$ black hole, i.e.,
$$A_h = \int\sqrt{\det{h}} \varepsilon_\partial = r_h^2\int_0^\pi\text{d}\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\text{d}\phi \sin(\theta) = 4\pi r_h^2.$$
Now, the trick is to consider a differential of the black hole volume as it grows in an interval $\text{d}t_E$. We have
$$dV = A_hdr \implies A_h = \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}r} = \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t_E}\frac{\text{d}t_E}{\text{d}r} \iff \int A_h \text{d}r = \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t_E}\int\frac{\text{d}t_E}{\text{d}r}\text{d}r = \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t_E}\int\text{d}t_E $$
where I have used that the growth rate of volume $(\text{d}V/\text{d}t_E)$ is constant. Now, integrating over the Euclidean periodicity and over AdS space, I have
$$A_h \ell_{AdS} = \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t_E}\int_0^\beta\text{d}t_E = \beta \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t_E} \implies \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t_E} = \beta^{-1}A_h\ell_{AdS} = TA_h\ell_{AdS}.$$
That's my best bet anyway, you may have to dig deeper into literature to find out if those assumptions are the one's Susskind used but this at least gives you a start.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late comment; just now got the time to look at this. This was quite helpful. I think you mean to say "$\textit{volume}$ growth rate is constant" (of course your statement can be made by assuming the C=V conjecture, but I was looking for a pure GR answer to go towards the conjecture). Also, the assumption of volume growth being constant is fair (https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2854).

Comment: I have another naive question about this calculation: would the equation being about growth in $\textit{Euclidean time}$ make a difference? It would give an extra factor of $\textit{i}$ making the growth rate imaginary, right?

Comment: @thunderbolt, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the solution to include _volume_ growth rate. The time signature surprisingly doesn't make a difference but I'll leave this as homework for you! (Here's a hint, use the chain rule; ${dV}/{dr} =( {dV}/{dt_E})({dt_E}/{dr}) = ({dV}/{dt_M})({dt_M}/{dr})$. You'll find that the _i_ cancels everywhere once you integrate appropriatly.)